# Will there ever be a second season of Firefly even after such a long hiatus?

Tags: firefly

Will there ever be a second season of Firefly? Is it possible?  Season 1 must be at least ten years old now. Are there any precedents where this kind of thing has happened before, following such a long hiatus?

Comment: Only in our most sacred dreams of the heart.

Comment: *"Are there any precedents"* Plenty, recently. Old shows are being resurrected left and right (X Files, Twin Peaks, Full House etc). But I wouldn't hold my breath on this one... :(

Comment: Reboots arnt the same thing Walt

Comment: @cde Those aren't reboots. They're continuations of the original plots with the original casts.

Comment: There's no way for us to answer this other than "maybe? If the planets align?"

Comment: @DA. You don't think it may be possible for others to know things that _you_ do not?

Comment: @tjt263 yep. It's certainly possible. I don't believe it's possible that if someone knows that there will be a new season, that that news will be broken to the world as an answer to your question here on StackExchange. It's not like Firefly is some niche show with a tiny fan base. If there was going to be a new season, you would have heard about it already.

Comment: Also, you're asking two very separate questions here. One is unanswerable (will there be a new season of Firefly) the other *is* answerable. I'll try answering the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Fox are keen on the idea, and have expressed their interest; but only as long as the original creator agrees to be involved.

> According to Fox President Of Entertainment David Madden, the option
>   for more Firefly is on the table. There's only one condition:
>
> Joss Whedon has to be on board if it's going to get made.

> Fox doesn't want to get involved without him. They know it could
>   be a hit, but they aren't willing to drop the show's identity.
>
> Madden was sure enough about his decision to mention that he wouldn't
>   even consider the possibility without Whedon's involvement.
>
> So, if you're hoping for more Firefly, look to Joss Whedon. It seems
>   to be in his hands now.

http://comicbook.com/2017/02/09/fox-will-move-forward-with-firefly-reboot-on-one-condition/

Answer (score 6):

> Will there ever be a second season of Firefly?

Anyone that has the ability to say 'yes' to that has not yet said 'yes' so at the moment, there is no sign that there will be.

When asked, the typical answer appears to be 'not likely'. [A recent interview with Nathan Fillion](http://www.esquire.com/entertainment/tv/interviews/a33827/nathan-fillion-alan-tudyk-firefly-reboot-tournament/):

> I honestly don't think that there's going to be another Firefly iteration.

In that same interview Alan Tudyk states:

> I'm for a Firefly reboot, personally. But it's going to have to be in a while. It's going to take a little time. I like the idea of it in another 10 years or so. We can pick up with Captain Mal, living on a moon somewhere…

So...maybe in another decade? :)

> Is it possible?

Anything is possible.

> Are there any precedents where this kind of thing has happened before, following a long hiatus?

Several:

- **[Arrested development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrested_Development_(TV_series))** = Season 3 ended in 2006. Season 4 started in 2013.
- **[The X-Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_X-Files)** = Season 9 ended in 2002. New miniseries starting in 2013.
- **[24](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_(TV_series))** = Season 8 ended in 2010. New miniseries started in 2014.
- **[Futurama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futurama)** = Season 4 ended in 2003. Season 5 began in 2008.

Many more examples can be found at [TVTropes list of *uncancelled* shows](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Uncanceled).

Comment: You might consider mentioning that a lot of the cast is busy elsewhere... for example, The likelihood of Nathan Fillion starring in two shows simultaneously is very low.

Comment: @Catija true, though I think the same could be said for many of the above...especially Arrested Development. (In addition, given the number of Firefly references used in Castle, perhaps having Castle and Firefly be some sort of crossover might be something Fillion would love :)

Comment: ... not to like... spoil *Serenity* for anyone, but why is anyone asking Tudyk what he thinks?

Comment: @Catija there's precedence. Obi Wan in the Return of the Jedi for instance. :)

Comment: I don't think he's going to come back as a ghostly guiding spirit... It'd be more likely that they would either ignore *Serenity* entirely or set the new show before *Serenity* happens.

Comment: @Catija but the same cast given there voices for the latest game. If they want they can.

Comment: @Catija For the record, Joss Whedon has said that he has ways to circumnavigate the issue we are talking about if they show was to ever come back.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Providing voices for a game takes what, a day? A couple of days? Which can be squeezed in-between other engagements. Acting in a TV show = long days, five/six days per week, for months on end.